# How to get birthdate, city, mobile number, state, country from FacebookSdk in swift 3

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch data from `FacebookSDK` , like user infromation `name, last_name. first_name, email` i am getting this details but i want more detials of user from there account like `birthdate, city, mobile number`, .. etc , i have added all parameters to `SDK` but i am not able to fetch other details of user  can anyone help me please, thank you , here is my code`

```
     let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
     fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.web
     fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions:       
     ["public_profile","email"], from: self) { (result, error) ->
     Void   in
     if error != nil {
      print(error!.localizedDescription)
      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      } else if (result?.isCancelled)! {
      print("Cancelled")
      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       } else {
       }
    }
    //id,name,birthday,email,last_name,location
     FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id,  
       name, first_name, birthday, email ,       
     location"]).start(completionHandler:
       { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbDetails = result as! NSDictionary

            print("fb details\(fbDetails)")

        }
    })
```

`

Comment: First of all you need to ask the user for the appropriate permissions to access those fields. And the mobile number is not available via API.

Comment: how can i fetch mobile number? @CBroe

Comment: username & phone number permissions are removed by Apple https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/01/14/platform-updates--new-user-object-fields--edge-remove-event-and-more/

Comment: ohhh , how can i fetch his birth date

Comment: @this.girish how Uber does this then?

Answer (score 2):

you can get as follows

```
let graphRequest:FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"first_name,email, picture.type(large)"])

            graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                if ((error) != nil)
                {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
                else
                {
                    let data:[String:AnyObject] = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                    print(data)

                }
            })
```

Comment: i want other details of user i.e. city , state, country, birth date , i am able to access picture, email ,name

Comment: you can get birthday by passing 'birthday' in fields array, and for city,state,and country you need to use 'location' for more info read this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Comment: i have added already all fields but cant able to get location, birth date, city please see my code & its parametors

Comment: you supposed to be an admin of an app then only they are accessible, if not then  you have to get your app reviewed by Facebook first.

Comment: login from admin account you will get all the info for sure. Good luck

Comment: @Asmita: this.girish answer will be helpful to you, this should work